# Sonarqube6.7 lack of 'import unknown files' option

Tags: sonarqube

I want to scan a text file such as how much line in a .sh file. In *sonarqube6.7* `unknown files = true` option is missing. I was in `sonar-project.properties` file to configure `sonar.import_unknown_files = true` also was not used. Does a higher version support unknown files?

Comment: Strange. If you look in the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code) section "Unrecognized files" it should be possible. But i cannot find this option in Sonarqube 6.7 and also not in the [parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) documentation page. Parameters do not use " _" always ".".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property sonar.import_unknown_files has no effect with SQ 6.7. By default, all the files are indexed (SONAR-8623). Then SQ keeps only the files on which a given Sensor (a plugin) saved something on it (SONAR-8631).

For your case, you need a custom plugin that:

- declares a new language dealing with .sh files (similar to: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/languages/FooLanguage.java)
- implements a Sensor implementing some logic to raise issues/metrics on your .sh files

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you said, I have defined my own plug-in to solves this problem

Comment: @DonnyTang, I am facing the same issue, would you share your plugin ?